# alf.nu random4 excercise, what is the answer?

Tags: javascript

I was playing on this [site](https://alf.nu/ReturnTrue#accesstoken=PtpFJro9GlDLFsfKRKgg), and I got stuck at the **random4** problem.

So, basically, the problem is the following.

```
var random4 = new function() {
  var rand = Math.random();

  this.test = function(x) {
    return rand === x;
  }
};
```

What value of `x` should be passed to `random4.test` in order to have it return `true`?

Note that the code here is slightly different from the linked page. This is because we do *not* have access to the `rand` variable and I want to make this explicitly clear.

Answer (score 4):

[`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) *can* be predictable, which can be exploited. In theory. The [ES6 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-math.random) says

> Returns a Number value with positive sign, greater than or equal to 0 but less than 1, chosen randomly or pseudo randomly with approximately uniform distribution over that range, using an **implementation-dependent algorithm or strategy**. This function takes no arguments.

*(Emphasis mine.)*

In practice, most modern browsers use [xorshift128+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift#xorshift.2B) ([Chrome](https://v8project.blogspot.nl/2015/12/theres-mathrandom-and-then-theres.html), [Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=322529#c99), [Safari](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=151641)). Its implementation is rather brief and can be understood relatively easily. See this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34432126/962603).

Can we attack this implementation and predict values in the sequence, or try to figure out previous values? According to [Security.SX](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/84906), we [can](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/110241). We [**really**](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/123554) can. It is definitely not easy, but possible.

I don't know if this can really be used to solve the linked exercise. In theory, it could.

---

An alternative could be to pass in something that will always be equal to any number compared to it. That is, overload the strict equality [`===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity_strict_equality_()) operator. Unfortunately, JavaScript does not support operator overloading, as far as I know. You can [cheat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/operator-overloading) and use post processing (cannot be used on the linked page), or [fake it](http://2ality.com/2011/12/fake-operator-overloading.html) in some cases, but this challenge is not one of them as we have primitives that are compared using the strict equality operator - that one does not do casting or `valueOf`.

Comment: lots of valuable info here, but this still doesn't solve the actual problem :(

Answer (score 0):

You simply pass the `rand` variable that you've already declared in:

```js
random4(rand);
```

`rand` is equal to `x` which is equal to `rand`.

```js
var rand = Math.random();
function random4(x) {
    return rand === x;
}

console.log(random4(rand));
```

Comment: the problem is that rand is defined in another context, therefore it is not accessible, you can try it there and you'll get "rand is undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Still trying this but it could be similar to

```
random4(
    Math.random = function(){return true}
)
```

Though this needs the function itself to be equal to its return value, thats the part Im not sure about

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6959642/1281385

Doesnt help here

Comment: rand is set to Math.random() prior to random4 being called, so no matter how you define Math.random, it's not going to make a difference.