# How does Javascript convert the result of xorshift128+ to a float value between 0 and 1 for Math.random()?

Tags: javascript, python, random

I need to write a program exploiting cryptographic insecurity of javascript's Math.random() for a CTF thing. However I do not know how javascript converts an int to a float between 0 and 1.
The pseudo-randomization algorithm of javascript, as far as I understand is xorshift128+, which in python would look something like this:

```
def cast_to_int32(x):
    return x & 0xffffffff


def xorshift128plus():
    global state0
    global state1
    state0 = cast_to_int32(cast_to_int32(18030 * (state0 & 0xffff)) + cast_to_int32(state0 >> 16))
    state1 = cast_to_int32(cast_to_int32(30903 * (state1 & 0xffff)) + cast_to_int32(state1 >> 16))
    return cast_to_int32(cast_to_int32(state0 << 16) + (state1 & 0xffff))
```

However bitwise operations in this scenario are performed on integers, not floats. But the result of javascript's Math.random() is a float between 0 and 1. How does javascript convert that? I know the most intuitive thing to suggest would be a simple division by 2^32 or 2^31 but I've tried that and couldn't reproduce the results.

I tried dividing the int result by (2^31-1),(2^31),(2^32-1),(2^32) but none of these reproduced the results of Math.random() from the same state.

Comment: Keep in mind that JavaScript numbers *as visible in JavaScript programs* are doubles, but inside the interpreter the code can do anything the platform can do.

Comment: To add to that, there's no rule that the JavaScript built-in object methods must be written in JavaScript. It's opaque, and only the behavior is specified.

Comment: `would look something like this` - how is that implementing xorshift128+? xorshift128 returns a 64bit result, and furthermore, you can't set the state of `Math.random()` so how are you even contemplating comparing?

Comment: Oh, I see what you've done ... The algorithm you've written in Python is `MWC1616` - which was the algorithm used in V8 up until almost 10 years ago; before it was replaced by `xorshift128plus`

Comment: The Python PRNG algorithm shown in the post looks alarmingly like the MWC1616 algorithm discussed [this V8.dev blog](https://v8.dev/blog/math-random?showComment=1450389868643#c2004131565745698275). Reading further the block note the original xorshift128+ implementation was adjusted again in V8 7.1 Related question about [xorshift12+](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34426499/5217142)